# Call Power BI Reporting server Api using Token Based Authentication

Tags: .net-core, power-bi-report-server, powerbi-api

Hope you are doing great!

I am creating a windows service(.net core) project that will fetch all the reports from Power BI Reporting Server and send emails to the users as per schedules. There will be a link in email to access the report or the report will be already attached (pptx,pdf,doc,txt) in email in whatever format the user has scheduled.

I have used Power Bi Reporting Server API using this reference link:
[PBIRS | 2.0 | Microsoft-Rs | Swagger](https://app.swaggerhub.com/apis/microsoft-rs/PBIRS/2.0)

My issue is that this api is accessible directly using windows credentials. I have called the api using CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredntials property inside HttpClientHandler class.
But this is not what we are planing in production environment.
I want to access these api using a custom authentication so that the user can just click that link which has a token/authenticated and can see or download/view the report. How do i configure my Power BI server to have custom authentication?

Can anyone please help me? Early response is appreciated.

Thank You!

Comment: not an answer, I just wonder how you achieved automatic export of a `pbix` file into `pptx`, `pdf`, and other formats for `Power BI RS`? I couldn't find a way to do it using their API.

Comment: @Alex i have not yet achieved that. Well thats what i want to achieve as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think pbi_rs dose not support token base authentication yet. but there is a solution to customize authentication.
[Custom Authentication on powerBI RS](https://github.com/Microsoft/Reporting-Services/tree/master/CustomSecuritySample)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29828892)